# How to create socket via socket() on MSVC?

Tags: c, visual-c++, sockets

I am porting linux app under win32 (msvc 9.0) and after finally finishing it, I'm experiencing non-default behavior on simple things as `socket()`.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int subsock;
    if ((subsock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        printf("Failed to open socket (ret value = %d)\n", subsock);
    }
}
```

This prints `Failed to open socket (ret value = -1)` every time. What is wrong and how to open socket on win32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call WSAStartup to initialize winsock before subsequent socket calls will succeed.

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int err;

/* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData)
if (err != 0)
{
    YourError!
}
else
{
    // success
}
```

For more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742213%28VS.85%29.aspx

Just request version 2.2 and be done with it.

Comment: I assume that when compiling code to dynamic library, WSAStartup() must be placed in DllMain().                                              Is that correct?

Comment: It's really unsafe to put code in DllMain - especially when it runs in another DLL.  Just have a helper function in your code that tracks whether or not WSAStartup has been called with a global variable (and calls WSAStartup it if needed).  Right before you create a socket or any other networking function, call your helper function.

Comment: Thanks. What if I'm cross-compiling UNIX src to Win32 and there are TONS of socket calls that I'm not even aware of which of them nees WSAStartup().                   What then?

Comment: You could just export an "Init" function out of your DLL and require consumers to call it.  Or just make the contract between your DLL and EXE such that consumers are expected to call WSAStartup ahead of time. I suppose you could put it in DllMain, but it would be a slight hack.